# How can i iterate over attributes in laravel models?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel model with many attributes. So, I need iterate over these attributes. How can I do this?
Something like this:

```
@foreach($model->attributes as $attribute)
// use $attribute
@endforeach
```

is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried doing that yet?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have an object, use `getAttributes()`:

```
@foreach($model->getAttributes() as $key => $value)
    // use $attribute
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

If these attributes were returned from a query, you can access the `Model` class directly:

**E.g.**

```
@foreach (User::all() as $user)
    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

or, you can access the model reference given to a template:

**E.g.**

```
@foreach ($user->permissions as $permission)
    <p>This is an user permission {{ $permission->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

See more in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops)